# Complexity of computing kissing numbers of triangles with given side lengths

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

**Question:** Given three positive integers $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that the
sum of any two of them is bigger than the third, how difficult is it 
algorithmically to determine the *kissing number* of triangles with side
lengths $a$, $b$ and $c$ -- that is, the number of such triangles in the plane
which can simultaneously touch one such triangle in at least one point each?

*Remark:* On the one hand, it seems quite possible that this can even be
done with a bounded number of steps (arithmetic operations, case distinctions 
etc.) for any choice of $a$, $b$ and $c$, but on the other -- is there an
obvious reason for this problem to be algorithmically solvable at all?

Comment: Isn't it a function of the smallest angle of the triangle?  Maybe also the ratio of the longest side to the shortest altitude?  Gerhard "Miniscule Experience With Kissing (Number)" Paseman, 2017.05.27.

Comment: Let R be the ratio of the perimeter to the smallest altitude, and N the smallest number such that N times the smallest angle is at least 2pi radians. I conjecture that N+2R is a strict upper bound for the kissing number, and that there is a family of isosceles triangles that approaches this bound.  Gerhard "Geometrical Conjecturing While U Wait" Paseman, 2017.05.27.

Comment: Also, the minimum is 12.  Gerhard "Taking Care Of A Detail" Paseman, 2017.05.27.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman So, are you sure that the kissing number of the equilateral triangle is not 13? (I surmise I've seen a discussion like that already somewhere). If you are, what is the closest (in any reasonable sense you want) to the equilateral triangle for which it becomes 13?

Comment: I was working in Euclidean geometry of two dimensions.   In that geometry, the upper bound is a little less than 13.  Of course, if you are working in hyperbolic geometry, the estimate doesn't work.  If you have an example of 13 (disjoint) unit equilateral triangles in the Euclidean (or any other) plane kissing the same unit equilateral triangle simultaneously, I'd like to see it.  Gerhard "Can Stand Being Proven Wrong" Paseman, 2017.05.27.

Comment: Also, as I understand it, 12 is the minimum for any triangle, not just equilateral.  Gerhard "Checking For Agreement On Understanding" Paseman, 2017.05.27.

Comment: For an example that is 13, I don't have that at present. For an example that is over 13, try 501,501,999.  Gerhard "Odd Examples While U Wait" Paseman, 2017.05.27.

Comment: @fedja: For equilateral triangles, it's indeed 12, and not 13 -- cf. e.g. Likuan Zhao, [The kissing number of the regular polygon](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X98000272).

Comment: Tangentially related: "[The kissing number of a square, cube, hypercube?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/117579/6094)."

Answer (score 3):

Too long for a comment:

*I think there is a reason, why this is algorithmically solvable.*

Given three side lengths $a,b$ and $c$, and a fixed number $k\in\mathbb{N}$, writing down all the (in)equalities, that prescribe $k$ non-intersecting triangles with side-length $(a,b,c)$ kissing a (fixed) triangle with the same side lengths yields a semi-algebraic set $C_k$; the configuration space of $k$ kissing triangles. For each $k$ it is decidable whether or not $C_k$ is empty (existential theory of the reals). Therefore an algorithm would start with  $k=0$, increasing the $k$ until the first $k$ is found such that $C_k$ is empty and then returning $k-1$ as the kissing number. (The fact that this algorithm terminates comes from the fact that there is an upper bound on the kissing number.)