# Kissing behavior of planar regions

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling

This post reworks a question that was stated in a slightly different form at [Convex region $C$ with least kissing number of copies of $C$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346563/convex-region-c-with-least-kissing-number-of-copies-of-c).

**Background:** Given a 2D region $C$ (not necessarily convex), let us define its kissing number $K_0$ to be the largest possible number of copies of $C$ that can be arranged around a central copy of $C$ (call this $C_0$) and touching $C_0$.  Note that the surrounding copies can have any orientation. We also define '$K_1$' to be *the largest number of copies of $C$ that can be arranged around a central $C_0$ such that the copies **do not** touch $C_0$ itself but touch a copy that touches $C_0$*. Basically, $K_1$ is the max number of copies that can be arranged as a 'second layer' around $C_0$.

**Question:** Given any $C$, if we need to find its $K_1$, is it sufficient to first arrange $K_0$ copies all kissing $C_0$ and then to arrange maximum number of copies all touching at least one of these $K_0$ copies? Are there $C$'s where such a 'greedy' approach fails (ie it is better to arrange a suboptimal number of copies as first layer and to build a second layer around this layout)? Does requiring $C$ to be convex have an impact on the question?

Note: Extensions of this question to $K_n$ and higher dimensions are obvious. The above linked page has a slightly different definition of $K_1$.