# 3d convex body with max kissing number with translates

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

**Ref:** [Convex region $C$ with least kissing number of copies of $C$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346563/convex-region-c-with-least-kissing-number-of-copies-of-c)

Given a convex body $C$, let us define its 'translate kissing number' $k_t$ as the largest possible number of translated copies of $C$ that can be put around a central unit $C$ and touching it at at least one point. Note that every unit $C$ has the same orientation.

**Question:** In 3D, is the cube the convex body with the largest $k_t$ (26)?

**Further questions:** We could go to other dimensions (In 2D, the square appears to be the best candidate with $k_t$= 8) or redefine kissing in 3D as "the contact between the bodies should have finite area", or "the contact should be along at least a finite line segment".

**Note:** This and some other questions were recorded at  http://nandacumar.blogspot.com/2018/10/variants-of-kissing-number-problem.html